# Switching between UIViewController - presentViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, ios6

The following code isn't working out for me. Whenever the method is called the app crashes What have i done wrong?

This code does use a storyboard format

in the .h file

```
@class SendVideoViewController;

...

@property (nonatomic) SendVideoViewController *sendVideoViewController;
```

in the .m file

```
#import "SendVideoViewController.h"
...
@synthesize sendVideoViewController;
...
- (IBAction)signMeUpButtonPressed:(id)sender {
termsAndConditionsViewController = [[TermsAndConditionsViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:termsAndConditionsViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
//[self.view insertSubview:termsAndConditionsViewController.view atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: If i could get some solid feedback just once from this website it would be nice. Please if you post an answer respond to the comments on that answer. I dont like to be told just what to write, i also like to know what it means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should read:

```
sendVideoViewController = [[SendVideoViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:sendVideoViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Right now you are instantiating a generic `UIViewController` class. In order to create an object of the type which you have defined in your `SendVideoViewController` class, you need to call `+alloc` on that class, not `UIViewController`. You might want to brush up on [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: thanks a ton. Im happy you explained it. most answers i see on here are just the straight code. but thank you for helping me understand

Comment: This code only brings up a black screen... do i need to insert a subview to the window?

Comment: I am using a storyboard by the way

Comment: No. It might be a black screen if there are no subviews and the background color is black. Have you set up the view in the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sendVideoViewController = [[SendVideoViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:sendVideoViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: this isn't working... do i need to add the view to the subview?

Comment: please it will be good if you post the code properly so that we can see it

Comment: This is all the code that is necessary. The "view switcher" code is in a void method that is called when a button on the storyboard is touched, but it crashes the app